# jQuery find() different order in IE and FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I try to find the first input fields on my page which have a parent div with a defined class. So to get the inputs in the order they are defined is important for me. Unfortunately Firefox gives me the elements in the inverse order than the Internet Explorer. Any ideas to fix that?

Example:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- Include jQuery -->
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <div class="inputContainer">
        </div>
        <div class="inputContainer error">
            <input name="input1"/>
        </div>
        <div class="inputContainer">
            <input name="input2"/>
        </div>
        <div class="inputContainer error">
            <span>
                <input name="input3"/>
            </span>
            <span>
                <input name="input4"/>
            </span>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script>
        var errorContainers = $('input:visible, div.selector').parents('.inputContainer').filter('.error');
        var firstErrorInput = $(errorContainers).find('input,div.selector').first();
        alert($(firstErrorInput).attr('name'));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not `$('.inputContainer.error > input').first()`? This should get them in order.

Comment: I edit the code to a working example. `$('.inputContainer.error > input').first()` does not do the trick, because I got no errors for input3. Using FF alert() return input1, IE return input3.

Comment: @CannyDuck: http://jsfiddle.net/chrisvenus/sR97k/4/ gives me the right output I believe. The only difference between this and the above from @FelixKling is the removal of the `>`... Does this do what you want? You are certainly using a very roundabout seeming selector set...

Comment: @CannyDuck: Ah I was eluded by your sentence *which have a parent div with a defined class*... the parent of `input3` is a `span` element. Of course if the input elements are not children, omit the child selector, like @Chris did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code alerts "input3" in Chrome(16), Firefox (6) and IE 8 (with and without compability mode).

Tested it with; http://jsfiddle.net/sR97k/

Notice that you´re wrapping your selector/selected elements multiple times like `$($($('selector')))` and this isn´t necessary.

```
var errorContainers = $('input:visible, div.selector').parents('.inputContainer').filter('.error');
var firstErrorInput = $(errorContainers).find('input, div.selector').first();
alert($(firstErrorInput).attr('name'));
```

This would be enough;

```
var $errorContainers = $('input:visible, div.selector').parents('.inputContainer').filter('.error');
var $firstErrorInput = $errorContainers.find('input, div.selector').first();
alert($firstErrorInput.attr('name'));
```

The following selector should be get the first `input` in an element with the CSS classes `inputContainer` and `error`;

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x = $('.inputContainer.error input').first().attr('name'); 
});
```

Making sure the DOM has loaded before attempting to read from it.

Comment: Ok, added the "error" class and I see what you mean but your script is messy and I´m not sure it´s doing what you´re asking for. My suggestion (in the answer) finds that first `input` once the DOM has finished loading. Anything else you´d like it to do?

Comment: You are fabulous. That did it like a charm.